# What, if any, relationship is there between Cloverfield, 10 Cloverfield Lane and The Cloverfield Paradox?

Tags: cloverfield, the-cloverfield-paradox, 10-cloverfield-lane, cloverfield-2008

I've been reading all sorts of things of late that seem to want to tie these three movies together (some are using the term "Cloververse"), despite not having the same directors, producers, etc. The most recent was today, which [implies there's a connection](https://comicbook.com/horror/2018/02/07/the-cloverfield-paradox-easter-eggs-cloververse/).

> While it has yet to officially be confirmed by those involved with the film, a running theory connects the two monsters seen in Paradox to the original Cloverfield monster.
>
> In a blink-and-you'll-miss-it moment during the film's first act, a silhouette resembling the original "Clovey" appears to be seen walking through the ruined city, just as Michael (Roger Davies) rescues Molly (Clover Nee).

Are these three films actually related? Are they just building on the vagueness of the original? If there is any connection, was it intentional?

Comment: I think in the Super Bowl commerical it was explicitly stated that there was a connection and that this film explains the origin of the creature. Somebody can find and post the trailer I'm sure

Comment: yup - the first trailer directly references the first film -
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L7pElZJaB2w

Comment: Similar question from sister site [What is the relation between The Cloverfield Paradox (2018) and Cloverfield (2007) and 10 Cloverfield Lane (2016)?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/85460/what-is-the-relation-between-the-cloverfield-paradox-2018-and-cloverfield-200)

Comment: While most of the connections in Paradox are mostly just sort of nods or vague references, the very last shot of the film is pretty explicit in demonstrating that *Cloverfield* and *Cloverfield Paradox* are now connected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If there is any connection, was it intentional?

Yes, but only in a marginal, after-the-fact fashion.

It is important to note that *The Cloverfield Paradox* was [originally a movie called *God*](https://www.theverge.com/2018/2/7/16988106/cloverfield-paradox-facebook-questions-jj-abrams-julius-onah-fan-theories-answers-video-debunked) [Particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cloverfield_Paradox) that had nothing to do with *Cloverfield*. After half a decade of production hell, it was picked up by Netflix and rebranded.

As such, the tie-ins were mostly anything they could add out-of-sequence. So we have some easter-eggs, a brief scene in the middle with some shadows, and the so-painfully tacked-on few seconds at the end. It's even more painful than the last scene of *Other People's Money*.

*10 Cloverfield Lane* underwent a similar genesis, starting as [*The Cellar*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10_Cloverfield_Lane) and then receiving some tie-ins after being picked up by Bad Robot. The tie-ins in this case were limited. I find that interesting, given that the plot structure could have easily been folded into the original without too much effort - replace the aliens with the Cloverfield parasites and you're gold.

> Are they just building on the vagueness of the original?

It appears Bad Robot [wants to make Cloverfield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloverfield_(franchise)) their analog of a "Marvel Universe", IE, a place where they can make any movie, add a few easter eggs, and brand it in hopes of making a silk purse out of a sow's ear. It seems to have worked in this case.

Comment: This is a commentary, not an answer.

Comment: The first two paragraphs clearly state the nature of the tie-in, which answers the OP's question "Are these three films actually related?". The answer is "yes, sort of", which I explain.

Comment: this has the makings of a good answer if the editorializing was removed and details / evidence provided (link to info about 'The God Particle', identify the easter eggs, etc.... overall I agree w/ @phantom42 that this is mostly a commentary with little in the way of detail

Comment: Mention things like the station crashing vs the item in the coney island video, or Tagruoto, or the fact that we see Clover in the last shot of *Paradox, and it could become an ok answer. Right now it's just a rant. What does the future of Netflix have to do with answering the question? Nothing.

Comment: One is not allowed to editorialize @phantom42? Then why are you doing it?

Comment: I can’t think of any answer I’ve posted that does so. Point me to one and I’ll gladly edit.

Comment: What is even the point of your last paragraph? That Netflix is doing poorly because _theater film critics_ are rating their movies poorly, despite _audience_ scores being good, or great in the case of _Bright_, and viewership numbers being exceptional (to the point that a sequel for _Bright_ was almost immediately greenlit)? **It sounds exactly like a formula for success when you take out your bias** and analyze things from Netflix's delivery model, not traditional cinema's. The soap-boxing here bemoaning movie quality makes me doubt the accuracy of the rest of your answer.

Comment: OMG, if you don't like it, make your own answer! Holy crap, people have spent more time complaining about my answer than it took to write it.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz - answers *on this site* aren't meant to be commentary or opinion forums, but objective and verifiable in general

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty good explanation on [NME](http://www.nme.com/blogs/the-movies-blog/cloverfield-paradox-ending-cloverfield-universe-connections-2236766).

> The Cloverfield Paradox suggests that the Cloverfield films all take place across several alternate timelines. The space crew in The Cloverfield Paradox are responsible for bringing monsters and aliens into all of the separate timelines (and therefore, all the separate films).